# Different view colors cause jiggling in Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Currently, I have a view that has a background color of `UIColor(netHex: 0x272727)`, call it `View A`. `View A` is in a scrollview. When I scroll, the other views in the scroll view render fine, but `View A` jiggles a bit in the direction of the scroll. `View A` returns to normal almost immediately, but the jiggle effect is still noticeable.

When I change the color of `View A` to `UIColor.red`, the jiggle stops. The background color of the content view that `View A` is in is `UIColor.black`.

Any ideas on how to fix?

```swift
import UIKit
import Cartography

class ViewA : UIView {
    
    lazy var leftLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = UIFont.makeSFRoundedFont(fontSize: 14, weight: .semibold)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        
        label.text = "ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF"
        return label
    }()

    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // When backgroundColor is gray (UIColor(netHex: 0x272727), it is more slowly rendered
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.isOpaque = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true

        
        
        self.addSubview(leftLabel)

        constrain(leftLabel, self) { child, parent in
            child.left == parent.left + 23
            child.centerY == parent.centerY - 0.275
            parent.height == 50
        }
    }
    
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks problematic: `button.pin(to: self)` ... you shouldn't be constraining a stack view's arranged subview (other than maybe its height or width)... or, actually, it looks like you're ***inserting*** a button as a subview?

Comment: @DonMag, good thought. I commented out the button pinning, but button keeps jiggling sadly

Comment: What is `CustomButton`? How are you adding and constraining elements? Are you running any other code while scrolling? Too many possibilities and unknowns. To get help, I think you'll need to put together a [mre].

Comment: @DonMag, totally, I ended up reducing the bug to find out that a simple color change removes the jiggle. The initial color that caused the jiggle was both `UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)` and `UIColor(netHex: 0x272727)` (comes out to the same color. But I tried changing it to `UIColor.red` and the jiggle is gone. Any idea why? The view is rendered on another view with a background color of `UIColor.black`

Comment: @DonMag question is now updated with more details.

Comment: I put your view in a black "container" view in a scroll view... I'm not seeing any "jiggling". Do you have other elements at top/bottom of this view, where you see a "gap" develop as you see the jiggle? Since it appears you have white text on a very dark background on a black background, it's possible it's just optical - that is, the contrast leaves a "ghost" on your retina. If you can put a simple project together that clearly demonstrates what you're seeing - on GitHub or file-sharing site - I'll take a look.

Comment: @DonMag, you're totally right. It ended up being this issue: https://medium.com/lookup-design/designing-a-dark-theme-for-oled-iphones-e13cdfea7ffe . Thank you for your help, and what a weird bug